# Create a DataFrame from list in lists (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, database, list, dataframe

I´m having trouble creating a dataframe on my list.

The list contains four columns, but instead it says on presente one column with data:

```
ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns.
```

The list itself is presented in this way:

```
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 559.64, 8.01, 0.5520765512479038]]
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 520.34, 7.44, 0.5393857093988743]]
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 556.72, 7.96, 0.5410827096899603]]
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 688.67, 9.84, 0.5845350761787548]]
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 625.3, 8.94, 0.5612954767824924]]
```

I know there is something happening due to the double [], but i can´t figure it out. Can´t someone help me?

Here is the code so far:

```
   for i in range(6):
    excel_file = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name=sheet[i])
    excel_file = excel_file.values.tolist()

    filtered = [x for x in excel_file if 'TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)' in x
                or 'TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO (A)' in x
                ]

    sheet_file = sheet[i]
    sheet_variable.append(sheet_file)
    wb_name.append(file_name)
    conab_data.append(filtered)

    print(filtered)

df_conab = pd.DataFrame(conab_data, columns=['Descrição', 'Preço/ha', 'Scs/ha', 'Part. %'])
df_conab['Local/UF/Ano'] = sheet_variable
df_conab['Fonte'] = wb_name

print(df_conab)
```

Comment: the excel you are reading have a header or empty line?

Comment: the word your looking for is "nested" lists. a list will give you a column, a nested list will give you rows, so `[1,2,3,4,5]` will be laid out vertically, `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]` will be laid out as 2 rows with 5 columns. any further nesting will add the deeper lists as a single element in your DF

Comment: @FelipeBonfante these excel files they do not present any headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could fix this with a for loop

```
overly_nested = [[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 559.64, 8.01, 0.5520765512479038]],
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 520.34, 7.44, 0.5393857093988743]],
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 556.72, 7.96, 0.5410827096899603]],
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 688.67, 9.84, 0.5845350761787548]],
[['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 625.3, 8.94, 0.5612954767824924]]]

for i, sub_list in enumerate(overly_nested):
    overly_nested[i]=sub_list[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(overly_nested)
print(df)
```

I'm sure theres a way to do this with `zip()`, let me experiment and I'll edit if I find it

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried something like this and worked!

Comment: this happens pretty often while importing from google sheets or excel, I just came accros the solution `overly_nested = [np.squeeze(i).tolist() for i in overly_nested]` to remove the innermost later of nesting

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
data = [
    [['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 559.64, 8.01, 0.5520765512479038]], 
    [['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 520.34, 7.44, 0.5393857093988743]],
    [['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 556.72, 7.96, 0.5410827096899603]], 
    [['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 688.67, 9.84, 0.5845350761787548]], 
    [['TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)', 625.3, 8.94, 0.5612954767824924]]
]

df = pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in data], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                              A       B     C         D
0  TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)  559.64  8.01  0.552077
1  TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)  520.34  7.44  0.539386
2  TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)  556.72  7.96  0.541083
3  TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)  688.67  9.84  0.584535
4  TOTAL DAS DESPESAS DE CUSTEIO DA LAVOURA (A)  625.30  8.94  0.561295
```

Comment: I think you could also make data into a numpy array and then drop an axis, which might be more performant if there are a lot of rows.